# How to get service layer to return a Mono::error when it fetches nothing from database

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, couchbase, project-reactor

I am using this code block to retrieve some data from Couchbase, but when it fails to fetch anything it does not invoke the `onErrorResume` block. Is there a way I can make this code invoke `onErrorResume` when it fails to find a document matching the key?

```
return referenceService.getReferenceTable(referenceKey)
    .flatMap(referenceTable -> {
        logger.info("reference table: {}", referenceTable.toString());
        Market market = getMarket(aggregate.getDate(), aggregate.getMarket(), referenceTable);
        aggregate.setMarket(market);
        return Mono.just(aggregate);
    })
    .onErrorResume(e -> {
        logger.info("Error getting reference table");
        return Mono.error(e);
    });
```

The service layer being use looks like this:

```
@Service("referenceService")
public class CouchbaseReferenceService implements ReferenceService {

    @Autowired
    private ReferenceRepository referenceRepository;

    @Override
    public Mono<ReferenceTable> getReferenceTable(String key) {
        return referenceRepository.getReferenceTable(key);
    }

}
```

Comment: For clarification, what do you mean "when it fails to fetch anything"? Do you mean it is an empty list/map, or it is an expected full-blown exception?

Comment: AFAIK it is not returning anything, including an empty list or map. The scenario is that there is no document existing on the database that has the specified key, so there is nothing to fetch. When I run end-to-end in this scenario, it does not invoke the logging statement in the flatMap block, nor does it invoke the logging statement in the onErrorResume block.

Comment: So it returns `null`?

Comment: AFAIK yes. But the framework provides the repository implementation (`extends ReactiveCouchbaseRepository<ReferenceTable, String>`) so I don't know for sure

Comment: Maybe break out the `get` to see what you're getting prior to the flatmap to see if you're getting an empty list or a null object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`referenceRepository.getReferenceTable(key)` is returning an empty `Mono` when a `ReferenceTable` with the given `key` is not found.

This is not an error condition from the repository's standpoint.  To treat an empty `Mono` as an error condition, you can use `.switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(...))` in your stream.

Here is your example with [`.switchIfEmpty`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#switchIfEmpty-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) applied:

```java
return referenceService.getReferenceTable(referenceKey)
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new RuntimeException("No reference table found with key " + referenceKey)))
    .map(referenceTable -> {
        logger.info("reference table: {}", referenceTable.toString());
        Market market = getMarket(aggregate.getDate(), aggregate.getMarket(), referenceTable);
        aggregate.setMarket(market);
        return aggregate;
    })
    .doOnError(e -> logger.info("Error getting reference table", e));
```

Also, I made two other changes to your example:

1. Since your `.flatMap` implementation was a synchronous 1-to-1 mapping, you can use `.map` instead, as I have done above.
2. Since your `.onErrorResume` implementation returned the same exception that was observed, you can use `.doOnError` as I have done above, allowing the original exception to continue to propagate.